# Getting a null reference on my page from a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I just upgraded my version of jquery to **http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js**
and after that I believe I started getting these errors. Does anyone know if this jquery function is somewhat out of date with the new changes or why it would be throwing this now?

```
function CheckBrochuresSelected(checkBox) {
    var dataList = checkBox.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var deliveryOption = $('.consumerbrochurerequest' > [id$ = '_rblDeliveryOption'])[0];
    var broxList = dataList.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var optionList = deliveryOption.getElementsByTagName('input');
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined**
    var broxLabels = dataList.getElementsByTagName('label');
    var travelPlannerIsChecked = false;
    var broxLabel = "";
    var eBrox = null;
```

Comment: This isn't correct, whatever the version : `$('.consumerbrochurerequest' > [id$ = '_rblDeliveryOption'])[0];`.

Comment: If you have jQuery, why are you using .`parentNode` and `.getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: Sorry should have added that I really only messed with the versioning of jquery this code was already there and somehow working with the C# pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.consumerbrochurerequest' > [id$ = '_rblDeliveryOption'])
```

should be a string:

```
$(".consumerbrochurerequest > [id$='_rblDeliveryOption']")
```

As you have it now, it evaluates to a boolean value (`false`) and without error since that is a valid array, and therefore a valid expression. But `$(false)` evaluates to `[]` (an empty array) and you attempt to access the first element.

Comment: So putting it into a string value would give me the actual value or a "true" boolean back or the actual array value?

Comment: Your selector is saying: get all elements that have the attribute `id` ending with `_rblDeliveryOption` that are a direct descendent of an element with the `consumerbrochurerequest` class. It will return those elements (if there are any). By using `[0]` afterward, it will select the first element in that collection.

Comment: Were you saying to just do
var deliveryOption = $(".consumerbrochurerequest > [id$ = '_rblDeliveryOption']")[0];
OR
var deliveryOption = $(".consumerbrochurerequest > [id$ = '_rblDeliveryOption']");??
If it was the first it broke when doing just the quotes.

Comment: Use `[0]` at the end to extract the first element of the set.

Comment: So our work around was to just manually call in that control name and get the elements out of it. Then the optionlist finds it that way instead of looking all around for it

Comment: What kind(s) of elements match `[id$='_rblDeliveryOption']`?

Comment: It was just three radio buttons, but the area in the consumerbrochurerequest has multiple ones so we figured the guy coding this was just trying to narrow it down the best he could instead of putting a named id-ed div that was already there and calling them in that way.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't recommend mixing jQuery functions with the standard DOM functions (like getElementsByTagName). I would suggest browsing the jQuery API Reference (http://api.jquery.com/). For example, you can select all radio options using `$(":radio")`.